# Do closed closet doors keep moths out?

Tags: environmental-health, entomology, clothing

[Some sites](http://www.reviewmylife.co.uk/blog/2011/06/29/how-to-get-rid-of-clothes-moths/) suggest that [closed doors](http://www.webanswers.com/for-fun/do-you-sleep-with-your-closet-doors-open-or-closed-ba3380) can [keep moths out](http://www.tangerineboutique.com/content/ICK_The_dreaded_clothes_Moth/1011). Others [report](http://www.toytowngermany.com/lofi/index.php/t17510.html) that keeping the closet doors closed does not help with moth control. So, does it?

Comment: Unless there is a notable claim that keeping closet doors is an effective means of controlling moths, I do see this as a valid skeptics question. If closing closet doors were sufficient, we wouldn't need mothballs, or cedar lining.

Comment: The edits help, but the first link supporting closed closet doors only suggests that a near air-tight seal will make the home "less attractive" to moths. The second link is as far from reputable as possible.  The third cites closed closet doors as helping make moth balls more effective, and does not claim that keeping closet doors closed will eliminate moths. I think more notable claims of closet doors preventing moth infestations are required.

Comment: @Beofett - I do not see the problem with this.  There is a notable claim of a common belief.   If we want to have a meta discussion about improving the quality of questions addressed I am all for that.  But I do not see a problem with the question as it currently stands.

Comment: @Chad My point is that I see no of evidence of a notable claim of common belief that "closed closet doors keep moths out", and none of the three links support that claim.

Comment: @Beofett - I guess logically it makes a better barrier than an open door or no door at all.  And the point could be made that the moths get in while the door is open.  I am not saying I believe this just that the claim is plausible and that my mother would tell me to close my closet so my cloths did not get eaten by moths.